# How to get the text of the div?

Tags: jquery, ajax, mouseover

I am populating the content of a div having display - none using AJAX. The code is as follows -

```
$(".event").mouseover(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");

    $(".hidden-div").html("");

    $.post("get-festival-desc.php", {
        festid: id
    }, function (data) {
        $(".hidden-div").html(data);
    });

    var fest_title = $(".hidden-div").text();
    alert(fest_title);
});
```

It works all well (checked by inspecting the element) and the "hidden-div" does get the required data. However I also want to alert the text of the "hidden-div" but that does not seem to be happening.

Is it because of display set to none or AJAX or something I am doing wrong ?

Comment: tip : It has something to do with asynchronous behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the problem with asynchronous callbacks. Try this:

```
$(".event").mouseover(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $(".hidden-div").html("");
        $.post("get-festival-desc.php", {festid: id},  function(data){

            $(".hidden-div").html(data);
            var fest_title = $(".hidden-div").text();
            alert(fest_title);
        });
 });
```

Basically, jquery would not wait for the value of `$.post()` to return before it would execute the rest of the code. So, you would have to alert the text in the callback, rather than outsite of it.

Comment: Seems logical :)
Will try and check out !

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
var fest_title = $(".hidden-div").html();
```